# Как выполнить SQL UPDATE и SELECT

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы arhive и valid_date с общим полем entity_id. Нужно записать в поле offer_archive 1 если valid_date+23:59:59 меньше текущего времени. В примере ниже, после выполнения запроса в ячейку с entity_id=3 должно записать 1.

[image: Две таблицы]

Выполнить запрос SELECT и отобрать все нужные поля у меня получилось. А вот как обновить нужные поля по условию я не понимаю.

Comment: А что у вас получилось до сих пор?

Comment: как то так? `update a set offer_archive = 1 from archive, valid_date as d where d.entry_id = a.entry_id and dateadd(day, valid_date, 1) < now()`

Comment: Даже в википедии написано как выполнить update, даже с примерами https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)  а условие пишется вроде `entry_id in (select entry_id from valid_date where valid_date < now() - interval 1 day)`

Comment: А какой тип у поля `valid_date`? как на скрине, так чисто `date`, без компоненты времени. И тогда какой смысл плюсить к нему с точностью до секунды?

Comment: В реальной базе формат даты DATATIME 22.12.2017 0:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаем это вот так:

```
UPDATE `archive` `a`
INNER JOIN `valid_date` `vd` USING (`entity_id`)
SET `a`.`offer_archive` = 1
WHERE TIMESTAMP(`vd`.`valid_date`, '23:59:59') < NOW();
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать про объединение таблиц перед обновлением!